# Parse image issue in Iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a array which have a one content image URL for key "Image". I want to show that image in my table view.
How to do it .Please give me suggestion.

Comment: place activity indicator until it gets down loaded

Comment: UItablView,and NSMutableArray,NSMusicDirectory read  from apple document also "https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage"

Comment: look at this link..... panagtakdo.com/files/MyAsynchronousImageLoader/MyAsynchronousImageLoader.zip

Comment: check it once http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/LazyTableImages/index.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
img_view = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    img_view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    img_view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,130, 75);
    activityIndicator = [[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge] autorelease];

    [img_view addSubview: activityIndicator];
    activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(50,30);  

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];
    NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]
                                        initWithTarget:self
                                        selector:@selector(loadImage:) 
                                        object:[[xmlParser data1] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];                
    [queue addOperation:operation];
    [operation release];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:img_view];


-(void)loadImage:(Book *)book
{
[activityIndicator startAnimating]; 

NSString *imgurl=[book image_url];
NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:imgurl];    

NSData *img=[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithData:img];

img_view.image=image;

[activityIndicator stopAnimating];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can search in google using "lazy loading image for tableview".
It is also available with apple example.